# Codeigniter and SCSS,

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, sass, scss-mixins

I hope you are doing fine. I am new with Codeigniter and I have developed the UI of my previous project with JS, SCSS, CSS & Bootstrap. Now, I am trying to develop that project with PHP. though after doing a lot of research I am still not able to find any way to use SCSS with codeigniter. Also, it would be nice if you guys will give any idea about how to USE SCSS, JS, CSS with codeigniter in an efficient way.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

CI and SCSS haven't need to be integrated, they work separately.  Already have a topic about that, read this [SASS with Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415738/sass-with-codeigniter) for a better explanation.